# What's the purpose of a diode to Vcc at an LM339 output?

Tags: diodes, comparator

I'm unable to figure out the purpose of this diode (1N4148) from the output of the comparator (LM339N) to V<sub>CC</sub>. It's not clamping anything as there's nothing that can pull that rail beyond V<sub>CC</sub>.

[image]

Comment: What is the ultimate load?  I suspect it's some sort of coil.  The first diode may be an attempt to dampen any kickback into the input op-amp (though it seems a hair paranoid).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When power supplies turn off, the diode discharges the capacitor, so it's empty when power supplies turn on again the next time.

I am guessing that this is a power on delay timer, because it reads "time" on the potentiometer, and because this is turning on a relay, so each time supplies are connected, it should have an identical delay.

Comment: How? There's no path to ground through the diode.

Comment: Yes there is. Through all components that consume power. And even via the resistors and potentiometre, clear path from VCC to GND. Unpowered device has 0V on the supply line compared to 0V ground, so effectively, VCC is at GND voltage when there is no power.

Comment: Then it's there to bypass the 3M resistor so it can discharge quicker through the whole circuit. Got it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, charges slowly via resistor on powerup, discharges quickly via diode on powerdown.